# How to use Bluetooth conference speaker/mic as input?

Tags: sound, bluetooth, microphone, input-devices

**UPDATE: After failing to get this working, I returned the device. I won't be able to try any new suggestions, but will still leave the question up in case it helps others.**

I have an "Anker PowerConf S3" and am trying to get input working on Ubuntu 20.04.

The device seems to pair easily and works right away as an output device. I am unable to get it to show as an input device and use it as a microphone. Can someone assist in getting the input functionality to work?

Here's what I see in my sound settings:
[image]

I can't get a screenshot to show the input dropdown, but here's what I see for options:

```
Multichannel input - hd webcam c615
Microphone - hd webcam c615
Microphone - usb audio
Digital Microphone - sof-hda-dsp
```

Interestingly, if I go to Google Meet (in Firefox) and look at audio settings I see the device listed as an input device, but it doesn't actually do anything.
[image]

Comment: You need first of all to change from A2DP (HiFi stereo, NO microphone) to the HFP (hands free, mono) and hope that it works.

Comment: Thanks ChanganAuto. The change makes a lot of sense. When I do that, I get some odd UI stuff - now when I have it as the output device and in HFP mode, the meter under the output section moves when I make sound, but I still don't have any way to have it recognized as an input device. Is there some other config I should be changing?

Answer (score 0):

Try PulseAudio settings maybe you will get it listed there

```
sudo apt install pavucontrol
```

open pusleaudio volume control application then navigate to input devices -> port

Comment: Thanks Utkarsh Chandra Srivastava. I installed pavucontrol and under the "input devices" tab am able to see "Monitor of PowerConf S3" (after selecting to  show all input devices. Other inputs show meters indicating they are picking up sound, but this one does not. I've made the change to HFP as @ChanganAuto suggested too. It's nice to see the device recognized, but I I think something is still wrong.

Comment: You can try this https://zambrovski.medium.com/using-bluetooth-headset-on-ubuntu-790ce6eecc2  can help.

Comment: Thanks Utkarsh Chandra Srivastava. Still no luck here. I've decided to return the device and get something different that hopefully will work better. I won't be able to test further updates here, but thank you very much for your attempts along the way!

Answer (score 0):

I have an "Anker PowerConf" **not S3** and was also struggling to get input working on Ubuntu 22.04 LTS.

Things that made it work for me:

- updated firmware of the Anker PowerConf to `41.80`
- reseted the Anker PowerConf [Instructions](https://support.ankerwork.com/s/article/How-to-Reset-a-PowerConf-Speakerphone)
- Connected it via USB-C

Speaker and microphone just worked by this time via USB-C.

So I tried my luck with the bluetooth-connection and after pairing it worked nicely.

[Bluetooth Connection Anker PowerConf](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dDd8g.png)

and then I switched back to USB-C and it still worked.

[USB-C Connection Anker PowerConf (Dropdown)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o9x2j.jpg)